# psql error for restoring pgsl backup on cmd

Tags: sql, postgresql, cmd, backup, restore

I'm having a hard time understanding what this error means. The command I used was:

```
psql -U postgres -d app -1 -f postgres.sql
```

and this is the error:

```
 psql:postgres.sql:1879: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored
     until end of transaction block

ROLLBACK
psql:postgres.sql:0: WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
```

Not really sure how to make a transaction in progress. This is the sql file that I was trying to import to postgresl: http://pastebin.com/2xMGhstd

Comment: `user.id = 1` does not exists, causing the inserts to `raffle` (and all that follows) to fail.

Comment: so whats the conclusion here?

Comment: Sorry where does the user_id = 1 go?

Comment: Your dump-data is inconsistent. (probably someone deleted the line with user#1) You could just add it manually with fake data, and try again.

Comment: could you show how it should look like

Answer (score 0):

As joop explained, your SQL file is inconsistent.

There is a foreign key constraint from `raffle.user_id` to `"user".id`, which means that for every value in `raffle.user_id` there must be a row in `"user"` where `id` has the same value.

Now there is no row inserted in `"user"` with an `id` equal to 1, but the script attempts to insert a row in `raffle` with `user_id` equal to 1.

That violates the foreign key constraint an causes an error. Once there has been an error in a PostgreSQL transaction, all you can do is `ROLLBACK`. Until you do that, all statements in the transaction will fail with the error you observe.

The only solutions you have are either to fix the data so that they are consistent or to give up consistency by removing the foreign key constraint.

**Remark:** it is a bad idea to choose a reserved SQL keyword like `USER` as name.

Comment: what is the foregin key constrain that i must remove

Comment: `, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user (id)`

Comment: You must catch the *first* error and fix that, then the others will go away.

Comment: The one that you receive first. The one on top of the output. Capture the output to a file to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

As @joop commented: your .dmp file is crippled because user_id=1 does not exist in the `users` table, but is referred in the `raffle` table. **Example**: run the next snippet, then **uncomment** the line with user#1 on it and run it again.

---

```
-- Drop the schema *after* usage
-- DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(120),
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE (email)
);
    -- UNCOMMENT the next line to also add user#1
-- INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,'Jim.Fake@nolive.co.uk');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(2,'osman.narnia@live.co.uk');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(3,'KimFake1@outlook.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(4,'jaakume@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(5,'omarblack@protonmail.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(6,'osman.everton@hotmail.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(7,'radoslaw@ganczarek.in');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(8,'kane1001@live.co.uk');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(9,'osman.soloking009@outlook.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(10,'Shum1945@fleckens.hu');
CREATE TABLE raffle (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        user_id INTEGER,
        colour VARCHAR(120),
        up1 VARCHAR(4),
        up2 VARCHAR(4),
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT _color_up1_up2_uc UNIQUE (colour, up1, up2),
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(1,1,'Blue','7c4c','5c7e');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(2,1,'Pink','635d','853f');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(3,1,'Plum','5e80','7611');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(4,1,'Aqua','937c','1b75');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(5,2,'Navy','1d9a','8914');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(6,1,'Grey','d869','fc97');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(7,4,'Rose','5fee','b31f');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(8,1,'Ruby','d5b4','e749');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(9,2,'Teal','cf0b','3bf5');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(10,1,'Gold','98a7','3079');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(11,1,'Jade','5c69','66f8');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(12,1,'Lime','156f','6b34');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(13,1,'Blue','7da3','d95b');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(14,1,'Pink','a63e','b9b6');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(15,1,'Plum','d989','71a5');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(16,1,'Aqua','7372','0682');
/****
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(17,9,'Navy','01b3','e444');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(18,1,'Grey','d679','0123');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(19,1,'Rose','5963','692d');
...
***/
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Did you also **uncomment** the line with `VALUES(1,'Jim.Fake@nolive.co.uk');` ?

Comment: schema tmp dosent exist