# Schema "tmp" doesn't exist inside SQL generated dump file?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, dump, tmp

I'm trying to import my SQL dump to psql but there is a problem (as mentioned in the title). I'm not to sure why this happens, and what to do against it.

This is the command I am using

```
psql -U postgres -d app -1 -f postgres.sql
```

This is the error in cmd

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents> psql -U postgres -d app -1 -f postgres.sql
Password for user postgres:
psql:postgres.sql:3: ERROR:  schema "tmp" does not exist
```

and this is my SQL file

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(120),
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE (email)
);
INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,'KimFake1@outlook.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(2,'osman.narnia@live.co.uk');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(3,'KimFake1@outlook.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(4,'jaakume@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(5,'omarblack@protonmail.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(6,'osman.everton@hotmail.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(7,'radoslaw@ganczarek.in');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(8,'kane1001@live.co.uk');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(9,'osman.soloking009@outlook.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(10,'Shum1945@fleckens.hu');
CREATE TABLE raffle (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        user_id INTEGER,
        colour VARCHAR(120),
        up1 VARCHAR(4),
        up2 VARCHAR(4),
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT _color_up1_up2_uc UNIQUE (colour, up1, up2),
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(1,1,'Blue','7c4c','5c7e');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(2,1,'Pink','635d','853f');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(3,1,'Plum','5e80','7611');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(4,1,'Aqua','937c','1b75');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(5,2,'Navy','1d9a','8914');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(6,1,'Grey','d869','fc97');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(7,4,'Rose','5fee','b31f');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(8,1,'Ruby','d5b4','e749');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(9,2,'Teal','cf0b','3bf5');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(10,1,'Gold','98a7','3079');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(11,1,'Jade','5c69','66f8');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(12,1,'Lime','156f','6b34');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(13,1,'Blue','7da3','d95b');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(14,1,'Pink','a63e','b9b6');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(15,1,'Plum','d989','71a5');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(16,1,'Aqua','7372','0682');
/****
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(17,9,'Navy','01b3','e444');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(18,1,'Grey','d679','0123');
INSERT INTO raffle VALUES(19,1,'Rose','5963','692d');
...
***/
COMMIT;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40747666/905902 was intented as an *example*, to teach you something about (missing) foreign key data. BTW: `DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tmp CASCADE;`

Comment: that is me who posted it i just want a easier answer how do i make tmp exist

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\Documents> psql -U postgres -d app -1 -f postgres.sql
Password for user postgres:
psql:postgres.sql:3: NOTICE:  schema "tmp" does not exist, skipping
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
psql:postgres.sql:15: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "us
ers_email_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(KimFake1@outlook.com) already exists.